# Can you help me with making date events dynamic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In our organization, we currently have 6 events that occur every year. These events occur on the following dates:

```
Dec 11 2011
Nov 04 2011
Nov 08 2011
Mar 15 2011
Jul 07 2011
Sep 02 2011
```

The date format is set as shown above.

On any given event, we would go through about 5 different parts of our code changing the dates.

For instance, we have our last event of the year coming up in Dec 11, 2011. We will have to go through our code manually changing these dates.

One of those controls look like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEventDte" CssClass="TextBox" Width="157px" Value="DEC 11 2011" />
```

I would like to create a table and call it Events. This table will have eventId - integer datatype with values from  1 to 6.

Then we would like to set conditionals. If eventId = 1, then

The control above should show a value of Mar 15 of the current year.

If eventid = 2, control should show a value of Jul 07 of current year.

I have to issues handling this.

One, how do I design the table so that table shows current year?

For instance, this current year is 2011 and the December event should show Dec 11 2011.
Next year, it should show Dec 11 2012??

Second, how do I ensure that the control reflects current event?

For instance, if eventId = 1, the control should display Mar 15 and the current year?

Can you please help?

Ok, below is the class. Can someone please help me with how to use it so that controls such as the one I posted above doesn't have to be manually changed anymore?

If an admin selects the eventdate, then it changes all parts of the code that use the eventdate.

How do I use this class to accomplish this?

```
Public Class SetDates

    Private dateList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)() With { _
        {"date1", "Dec 11 2011"}, _
        {"date2", "Nov 04 2011"}, _
        {"date3", "Nov 08 2011 "}, _
        {"date4", "Mar 15 2011"}, _
        {"date5", "Jul 07 2011"}, _
        {"date6", "Sep 02 2011"} _
    }


    Public Function NewDate() As DateTime
        ' we work with the current date { DateTime.Now} 
        Return Convert.ToDateTime(dateList("date1"))
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a simple class with a method that will return the appropriate string (from your list of 6) after checking the current date.

Use this class in every location you need to display this string, and you will not need to update your code on date changes anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much Oded. Can you please give me an example?